# не передается bundle

Tags: android, kotlin, android-bundle

так отправляю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

так получаю

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

помогите разобраться в чем проблема

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галку слева от него.

Comment: точно, спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему вы никак не добавляете данные в саму навигацию, а только создаете bundle с ней. Делается это так (например):

```
override fun onClick(v: View) {
   val amountTv: EditText = view!!.findViewById(R.id.editTextAmount)
   val amount = amountTv.text.toString().toInt()
   val action = SpecifyAmountFragmentDirections.confirmationAction(amount)
   v.findNavController().navigate(action)
}
```

либо как в вашем случае:

```
val bundle = bundleOf("amount" to amount)
view.findNavController().navigate(R.id.confirmationAction, bundle)
```

Более подробную информацию можно найти в [документации](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-pass-data) и примеры того как работать с передачей информации между экранами.

***P.S. код лучше прикладывать текстом, а не картинками***